# Webfont on mobile - Targeting certain h1,h2's but not other elements

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, webfonts

**Background**

I am expecting that, the webfonts used on my site would work on mobile devices exactly as they are on desktop. This is, working as expected on desktop.

**CSS**

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'sdFont';
        src:
            url("/fonts/sdFont.woff") format("woff"),
            url("/fonts/sdFont.svg") format("svg"),
            url("/fonts/sdFont.eot"),
            url("/fonts/sdFont?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype");
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

        h1, h2, h3,h4,h5 {
             font-family: 'sdFont', Arial, serif;
        }
```

**Problem**

On Android Firefox The H1, H2 are working with the correct webfonts, the h3 and h4 however are not.

On Android Chrome none of the webfonts are working.

I don't understand how on firefox some of the fonts would work, yet on other elements would not :/

Comment: -1, could i get an explanation please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that my CND was:

http://sexdiaries.co.uk

But I was viewing the site at:

http://www.sexdiaries.co.uk

So, for web fonts when viewing them the CND needs to match the global URL. Bit odd, but its defiantly what happened in my situation.